# Japanese company transfer to contractor in Turkey rejected by Rakuten bank without disclosing reason

Tags: banking

I am a freelance contractor working with a Japanese client.
My nationality is not Turkish and I used to get payment in my home country from them with no problems.

Then I moved to Turkey recently and opened an account on one bank that allows opening account with passport and address in home country.

The client company sent me the new bill payment to the Turkish account and it took so long then was rejected by Rakuten bank.

The client company sent an inquiry and Rakuten bank said it can't disclose the reason. Then the client company sent to my home country's bank and it only took 2 days before arriving.

Why would Rakuten bank accept payment to me in my home country's bank but reject it to my Turkish bank even though all the beneficiary data is the same (even the address is my home country's address). The only difference is the phone number.

Shall I make the client company try the next payment to my Turkish bank?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: IMHO off topic - this is about business account bank interaction, not personal finance. The complex multi country nature makes it way out of scope of personal finance questions.

Comment: Since US accused some bank in Turkey is helping Iran to dodge the sanction, so a Japan bank may refuse business if they deems it is too troublesome or too risky.

Comment: @mootmoot Thank you! That might be the case. Even though the bank I have account in is not Halkbank, it might be related to the incident.